# Are these 2 require statements the same in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is:

```
require './test_req.rb'
```

same with this:

```
require './test_req'
```

and this

```
require_relative 'test_req.rb'
```

in Ruby? I have been researching the difference between these 3, and can't seem to find any functionality-wise.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the first two statements. They look the same

Comment: @RichardHamilton sorry I removed the extension from the second example, it was a typo.

Comment: Can.you not answer this yourself with some simple tests?

Comment: `require` is capable of loading a file without the `.rb` extension because it can also loads many other types of files. That you do not have to use the extension of a filename is simply a feature. `require_relative` differs from `require` in that it loads a file with a relative location to the file calling it.

Comment: You ask the question but still complain to the answerer that you know the answer? There is a difference functionality-wise, and @RichardHamilton described it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is:
>
> ```
> require './test_req.rb'
> ```
>
> same with this:
>
> ```
> require './test_req'
> ```

No. The first one will look for a file named `test_req.rb` in the current working directory. The second one will look for an implementation-defined set of files in the current working directory. YARV will look for `test_req.rb`, `test_req.rbw`, `test_req.so`, `test_req.dll`, and `test_req.dylib`. JRuby will look for `test_req.rb`, `test_req.rbw`, `test_req.so`, `test_req.dll`, `test_req.dylib`, `test_req.class`, and `test_req.jar`. Rubinius will look for `test_req.rb`, `test_req.rbw`, `test_req.so`, `test_req.dll`, `test_req.dylib`, and `test_req.rba`. (Note: this list is from memory, I didn't double-check it.)

Note that both of these should *never* be used. The current working directory is outside of the control of the script. In the best case, this can lead to a brittle script which will sometimes fail with a `LoadError` depending on whatever the current working directory happens to be when the script is executed. It's even worse, though: not only is the current working directory outside of the control of the script, it is under the control of the caller. Which means that the caller can inject arbitrary code into your script by providing his own `test_req.rb` in some directory under their control and setting that directory as the current working directory before calling your script.

That's why `.` was removed from the `$LOAD_PATH` in Ruby 1.9, and that's why you should never use it.

> and this
>
> ```
> require_relative 'test_req.rb'
> ```

This is not equivalent to either of the other two. This will look for a file named `test_req.rb` in the same directory that the currently executing file is in rather than the current working directory.